# DB Error: Configuration error. Unsupported database driver: roundcube

Tags: roundcube

I copied over an existing roundcube installation from one Debian wheezy system to another Debian wheezy. But I keep getting the following error in the log and empty page loads:

> DB Error: Configuration error. Unsupported database driver: roundcube

The db is Mysql and it's accessible with the credentials from the given host.

Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: Which version of roundcube are you using? How have you checked the database connection?

Answer (score 3):

More than likely something is wrong with your database connector string. Check in your Roundcube installation directory. Inside your config directory you should have a `config.inc.php` file.

Within this check your database connection string: `$config['db_dsnw']`

For example, with MySQL this could be:

```
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://dbuser:dbpassword@localhost/dbname';
```

Comment: $rcmail_config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://webmail:pass@10.0.0.12/mail_roundcube'; Yes this is the mysql connection string as I said I rsynced everything from other working server. The db credentials are working because I tested them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check inside the file `/etc/dbconfig-common/roundcube.conf` if this variable it's established to mysql

```
dbc_dbtype='mysql'
```